# Replace 3rd+ occurrence

Tags: regex

How can I replace 3rd+ occurrence of a string? I want to keep first and second new lines but replaces all others with empty string in Dart but the question itself is language agnostic

I want to convert

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

to

```
a
b
cdef
```

Comment: `(?<=\n[^\n]*\n.*)\n` if the language supports variable-length lookbehinds

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: `javascript` or `java`? You have to choose.

Comment: No matter, `javascript` if you prefer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following,

```js
const s = 'a\nb\nc\nd\ne\nf'
const chunks = s.split('\n')
console.log( [chunks[0], chunks[1], chunks.slice(2).join("") ].join("\n"))
```

Splits with a newline character first, then takes the first two items and joins the rest with a newline character.

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe not the best solution, but it works:

```dart
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  final input = '''
a
b
c
d
e
f
''';

  final output = input.replaceFirstMapped(
    RegExp(r"(([^\n]+\n){2})((.|\n)+)"),
    (m) => "${m.group(1)!}${m.group(3)!.replaceAll("\n", "")}",
  );
  
  print(output);
}
```

Comment: I think `split` and `join` is better